# Unexpected assertion failed error when comparing objects using ,equals()

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array, junit

Why am I getting an assertion failed error here when I compare 2 objects with the same values using an add method for adding matrices. Below is my add method (from AbstractMatrix):

```
public abstract class AbstractMatrix implements Matrix{

private static MatrixFactory factory = new DefaultMatrixFactory();
private Matrix getNewMatrixInstance(Matrix kind,int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns)throws MatrixException{
    return factory.getInstance(kind.getClass(), numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
}
public static void setFactory(MatrixFactory aFactory){factory = aFactory;}

public final boolean isSameSize(final Matrix m){
    return (getNumberOfRows() == m.getNumberOfRows()) && (getNumberOfColumns() == m.getNumberOfColumns());
}

public final Matrix add(final Matrix m) throws MatrixException{
    if (!isSameSize(m)){
        throw new MatrixException("Trying to add matrices of different sizes");
    }
    final Matrix result = getNewMatrixInstance(this, getNumberOfRows(), getNumberOfColumns());

    for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < getNumberOfColumns(); column++){
            final double value = getElement(row, column) + m.getElement(row, column);
            result.setElement(row, column, value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is my JUnit test:

```
@Test
void testAdd() throws MatrixException {
    Matrix m1 = factory.getInstance(ArrayMatrix.class,new double[][]{{0,0},{0,0}});
    Matrix m2 = factory.getInstance(ArrayMatrix.class,new double[][]{{0,0},{0,0}});
    Matrix m3 = m1.add(m2);
    Matrix m4 = factory.getInstance(ArrayMatrix.class,new double[][]{{0,0},{0,0}});
    assertEquals(true, m3.equals(m4));
}
```

Clearly m3 is the same matrix as m4 but I get an AssertionFailedError telling me that it is false.

Other classes:

```
public class ArrayMatrix extends AbstractMatrix{

    private double[][] elements;

    public ArrayMatrix(final int rows, final int columns) throws MatrixException{
     // Initialise a new matrix with all the elements set to 0.0
        if (rows < 0 || columns < 0) {
            throw new MatrixException("Negative rows or columns are not allowed");
        }
        this.elements = new double[rows][columns];
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<columns;j++) {
                elements[i][j]= 0.0;             
            }        
        }
    }
    public ArrayMatrix(double[][] content) throws MatrixException{
 // Initialise a new matrix storing the data provided by the
 // double[][] parameter.

        int rows = content.length;
        int columns = content[0].length;
        elements = new double[rows][columns];
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<columns;j++) {
                elements[i][j] = content[i][j];
            }
        }      
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows(){
 // Number of rows in matrix
        int noRows = elements.length;
        return noRows;
    }

    public int getNumberOfColumns(){
 // Number of columns in matrix
        int noColumns = elements[0].length;
        return noColumns;
    }

    public double getElement(final int row, final int column) throws MatrixException{
         // Return the element at the specified position or throw an exception
        if (elements.length<=row) {
            throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");
        }
        if (elements[0].length<column){
            throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");
        }
        else {return elements[row][column];}
    }

    public void setElement(final int row, final int column, final double value) throws MatrixException{
         // Set the element at the specified position or throw an exception
        if (elements.length<=row) {
             throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");}
        if (elements[0].length<column){
             throw new MatrixException("Attempt to access invalid element ("+row+","+column+")");}
        else {elements[row][column] = value;}
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface Matrix {
    public int getNumberOfRows();
    public int getNumberOfColumns();
    public double getElement(final int row, final int column)throws MatrixException;
    public void setElement(final int row, final int column, final double value)throws MatrixException;
    public Matrix add(final Matrix m) throws MatrixException;
    public Matrix subtract(final Matrix m) throws MatrixException;
    public Matrix multiply(final Matrix m) throws MatrixException;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using assertEquals(<bool>, <expression>) instead of assertEquals(m3, m4)?

Comment: @K.Dackow That also doesn't work. I get this error : https://imgur.com/a/UWfmZlC

Comment: Please *edit* your question and post your code as a [mcve]. Do not post links to images of code, images of errors, or code on other sites. When these links go stale, your question is pointless. It's also a pain in the lower end of the back to scrape the information for your question from 10 different pages. Make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: @Robert Note taken, just didn't want to clog up the entire page with code,

Comment: That's why people ask for a *minimal* example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you posted, it does not appear that the `ArrayMatrix` class has an overridden `.equals()` method. The default `.equals` compares objects based on [location in memory](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java), thus the error in the screenshot you posted.

To fix this, you can [write your own](https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) `.equals()` method that compares arrays based on what's inside of them!